# Oracle Undo tablespace after commit and record stored after undo_retention is crossed?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, undo, tablespace, flashback

When I commit a transaction in oracle, it looks like my undo segment is released. Where does my old values go after commit?

What happens to undo tablespace after we commit a transaction?

And when we flashback the table, it looks like we can still recover records even after the undo_retention is crossed, Where was the record stored during this interval?

Answer (score 1):

This is described in Documentation, Database administrator's guide, [Managing Undo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/undo.htm#ADMIN013); link is to 11gR2, find your version if necessary.